# Сохранение файла не работает

Tags: c++, qt

```
    // тутечки проблемма
    // тут сохраненине файла, бинарника

    char fname[255];
    sprintf((char*)fname,"%s",file_name.toLocal8Bit().data());

    fname = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "Результаты" + "/" +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ssss")+ ".bin";

    if(file_name.isEmpty())
            {
                qDebug() << "хпреньа11 печенька ";
                return;
            }

            char fname[255];
            sprintf((char*)fname,"%s",file_name.toLocal8Bit().data());

    FILE *fid=0;
    fid=fopen(fname, "wb");

    qDebug() << "K" << obm->stor->K << "NT" << obm->stor->NT;
    if(fid)
    {
        fwrite(obm->stor->RE,sizeof(double),obm->stor->K*obm->stor->NT,fid);
        fwrite(obm->stor->IM, sizeof(double),obm->stor->K*obm->stor->NT,fid);
        fclose(fid);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error save Re & Im! " << fname;
    }
    qDebug() << "END";
```

fname  C:/Works/contr_glsso1/Результаты/2016-08-16_12-06-0808.bin

Error save Re & Im!  C:/Works/contr_glsso1/Результаты/2016-08-16_12-06-0808.bin 
вот как он отрабатывает .

Пишу в qt по этому думаю может через QFile записать в фаил , но мне сказали что записывает он как то не правильно.

Comment: Это называется не "не работает", а "не собирается". И ваша конвертация к ошибке отношения не имеет, посмотрите на какую именно строку ругается компилер.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fname = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "Результаты" + "/" +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ssss")+ ".bin";
```

В общем проблема в языке, заменив название директории на  на англ прекрасно работает .

Пример:

```
 fname = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "DDR" + "/" +  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ssss")+ ".bin";
```

Comment: логично, потому что toLocal8Bit и кириллица дружат хитро. На самом деле в Вашем коде такие извращения, что даже комментировать не хочется.